# Optimising SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, optimization

I am using a stored procedure in SQL Server to retrieve transactions from a `Transaction` table with a huge amount of data.

I want to filter the transactions with transactionids, merchantids, processorids, gatewayids etc and etc.

Each parameter is passed to the stored procedure as comma-separated values of type `varchar`, for example `('100,101,200,205')`.

I want to filter transactions with these parameters. Now I'm using for example inner joining the transaction table like this.

```
INNER JOIN
    STRING_SPLIT(@TransactionIds, ',') AS TMT ON  TMT.value = CONVERT(varchar(50), TXN.TransactionId)
```

This is taking a lot of time. Can you suggest some optimised methods?

Comment: the convert(varchar(50),TXN.TransactionId) will cost you.  Is it necessary ?   Assuming TransactionID is an INT, convert VALUE to an INT

Comment: Suggest you read [kitchen sink example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and erland's [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) to better understand the issues.

Comment: which is better ? inner joinig with table created from string_split() function or adding in condion in where clause by selecting value from string_split() function

Comment: Only one way to know - try both with good quality sample data and measure. Guessing is not the best way to diagnose performance issues - you need to examine the execution plans. As already noted, applying a function (CONVERT) to a column for comparison is a bad idea.

Comment: Why are you passing delimited strings as parameters? You should look into table valued parameters. That way you don't have to split them, you just treat them like a standard table. But really if you want help optimizing your procedure you should post all of it, not just a portion.

Answer (score 0):

Take separate parameter for every input field
also you can apply index to the parameter which you are using during joins or
in where conditions

- Applying index will defiantly improves your query performance